# Networkx Graph plot node weights

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I would like to assign node weights to each node in an undirected graph. I use the following MWE:

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(0)
G.add_node(1, weight=2)
G.add_node(2, weight=3)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Then I have a figure of the following form:
[image]

I would like to plot a graph with the weights given in a new color next to the nodes, such as:
[image]

What is the easiest way to implement this? On SO the materials are mostly for edge weights, or changing node sizes w.r.t. the node weights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `labels` attribute with corresponding dict and `node_color` attribute with corresponding list. For this code:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(0, weight=8)
G.add_node(1, weight=5)
G.add_node(2, weight=3)
labels = {n: G.nodes[n]['weight'] for n in G.nodes}
colors = [G.nodes[n]['weight'] for n in G.nodes]
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, labels=labels, node_color=colors)
```

Networkx will draw:

[image]

If you want to draw both node ID and its weight, you can write something like this:

`labels = {n: str(n) + ';   ' + str(G.nodes[n]['weight']) for n in G.nodes}`

---

If you have missing `weight` attributes in nodes and want to draw them, you can use this code:

```
labels = {
    n: str(n) + '\nweight=' + str(G.nodes[n]['weight']) if 'weight' in G.nodes[n] else str(n)
    for n in G.nodes
}
```

I think it is nearly impossible to draw weights **near** nodes with **different** color. It is the best I can suggest to you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! However, I don't want to change the colors, and only add the weights next to the original node index. Your last line `labels = {n: str(n) + ';   ' + str(G.nodes[n]['weight']) for n in G.nodes}` does not work in my code. Is there any method to generate what I want?

Comment: You should set `weight` attribute for each node for this code to work.

Comment: At least it works, but I hope there is an even more precise way :)

Comment: Updated the answer.